# Filter Array of Object from another Array of Object

Tags: arrays, json, object

Currently I'm filtering data based from questions that have checked property value equals to true..

```
const data = [
             {Name: "foo", X1: "1", X2: "1", Other: "Test1"},
             {Name: "bar", X1: "2",X2: "2",Other: "Test2"},
             {Name: "test",X1: "2",X2: "3",Other: "Test3"}
];
const questions = [{rows: {text: "Text 1", checked: true,fields: "1",column: "X1"}
}, {rows: {text: "Text 2", checked: true,fields: "2",column: "X1"}
}, {rows: {text: "Text 3", checked: false,fields: "1",column: "X2"}
}, {rows: {text: "Text 4", checked: false,fields: "2",column: "X2"}
}, {rows: {text: "Text 5", checked: false,fields: "3",column: "X2"}
}];
 console.log(questionArr);
// console.log(dataArr);
const res = data.filter(d => questions.find(f => d[f.rows.column] === f.rows.fields && f.rows.checked));
```

which works but does not work when filtering the actual data below. I think there's a slight difference between the question object and the actual question object below.. What should be my filter code when accessing these kind of structure ?

[image]

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: only the data with the questions that have a value of true in checked property so in the two array only foo must return.. since it only have X1 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. I matched the data structure to the image in your question. Let me know if I missed something.

```js
const data = [
 { Name: "foo",  X1: "1", X2: "1", Other: "Test1" },
 { Name: "bar",  X1: "2", X2: "2", Other: "Test2" },
 { Name: "test", X1: "2", X2: "3", Other: "Test3" }
];

const questions = [
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 1", checked: true, fields: "2", column: "X1" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 2", checked: true, fields: "2", column: "X1" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 3", checked: false, fields: "1", column: "X2" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 4", checked: false, fields: "2", column: "X2" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 5", checked: false, fields: "3", column: "X2" }] }
];


const result = data.filter(function(item){
  return questions.some(function(question){
    return question.rows.some(function(row){
      return (row.checked && item[row.column] === row.fields);
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

The compact version

```
const result = data.filter((item) => questions.some((question) => question.rows.some((row) => (row.checked && item[row.column] === row.fields))));
```

With perf in mind

```js
const data = [
 { Name: "foo",  X1: "1", X2: "1", Other: "Test1" },
 { Name: "bar",  X1: "2", X2: "2", Other: "Test2" },
 { Name: "test", X1: "2", X2: "3", Other: "Test3" }
];

const questions = [
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 1", checked: true, fields: "2", column: "X1" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 2", checked: true, fields: "2", column: "X1" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 3", checked: false, fields: "1", column: "X2" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 4", checked: false, fields: "2", column: "X2" }] },
  { rows: [{ text: "Text 5", checked: false, fields: "3", column: "X2" }] }
];

const result = {};

for(let a = 0, b = data.length; a < b; a++){
  const item = data[a];

  for(let c = 0, d = questions.length; c < d; c++){
    const rows = questions[c].rows;

    for(let e = 0, f = rows.length; e < f; e++){
      const row = rows[e];

      if(row.checked && item[row.column] === row.fields){
        result[item.Name] = item;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// this could be replaced with Object.values(result);
const matches = [];

for(let match in result){
  matches.push(result[match]);
} 

// not supported by IE yet
// Object.values(result);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: both code works perfectly, but what if the rest of the rows matter? From the given example objects, no data should appear since none of the column X2 was checked even both column X1 was checked?

Comment: its okay now I used every instead of some. THanks again